# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (.)

Tags: javascript, render, liveserver, onrender

[image: error message]

I used the render site for using my project as a live server and also used the vercel site for deploying my project.
Everything should be alright there is no error, but when I click my live server site name and run it, it shows an error which I give a picture of this issue.

What should I do next to solve this problem? I already recheck a couple of times and Everything goes alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP status 500 mean [Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500). You should check your server error log.

Comment: Could you explain more about this? Or give an idea that makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Some resources for example images or js or CSS files not found. Probably after unloading the project in the live server. Some photos, js, or CSS file paths are not found or are not readable.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).